# Does launching a new activity destroy my networking Service/AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I am tinkering and building on Google's own WifiDirect code (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect). I am passing a boolean, and displaying this boolean in a new activity once passed.

I've managed to make a connection, which causes the new activity to be launched, but nothing gets passed.

1. The demo contains both FileServerAsyncTask (for the GroupOwner), and FileTransferService(client). A few questions:

   - A.   As a groupOwner/Server, when FileServerAsyncTask gets executed,
     does it stay active forever?
   - B.   How would a UI ”know” when it has successfully received something,
     and should update accordingly? FileServerAsyncTask possesses a
     OnPostExecute() section – but how should I update the host activity?
   - C.   Where should I call FileServerAsyncTask? As soon as a contentView
     is loaded, as its done in the demo? Would it work if tied to a
     button?
2. As mentioned before, as soon as I make a connection, I start a new activity, with its own UI. This in itself is probably dumb.

   - A.   Is this bad practice? Will it interfere with the networking code within WifiDirectActivity & its two fragments. (As it currently doesnt seem to work properly)
   - B.   Will WifiDirectActivity be destroyed then? Since a new activity is running
   - C.   If this is bad practice, and I should consider using a new fragment, will replacing the two previous fragments somehow affect functionality as well?

I apologize for the composite question!

---

Code Added
WiFiDirectActivity
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/25657f080131d4b14528983006fbf272

BroadCastReceiver
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/0c42da764e26ef8a51417c6a9e5f3a76

DeviceListFragment
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/ccfb7685f0a5f5dcf599336f79c49ba8

DeviceDetailFragment
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/e70169b64ac3b7feca3f945164b62781

ConsentActivity (new Activity)
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/e3b4d581cc3634f9a15809725b66bcf6

FileServerAsyncTask (ripped from DeviceDetailFragment)
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/850ad02f81c03b29b141b3e19f4515c9

FileTransferService
https://gist.github.com/EXJUSTICE/81780db849729ce2fa0550fdd9db49bf

Comment: Will you please post your code, it will be lot easier to suggest changes

Comment: THe answer to your question in the topic is no.  Services exist until stopped, unless they are bound but not started (in which case they end when the binder is done).  AsyncTasks end when doInBackground returns.

Comment: Code added. My doInBackground has as its last line, return DataInputStream.readUTF().. So this means it will keep running till it receives files from the client right?